# What Schema.org type to use for a technology training course?

Tags: schema.org

I am working on a website that hosts online and classroom based technology training courses like AngularJs, HTML5 Training etc.

What is the structured data type to be used for Schema.org implementation?

Following are the options:

- `Product`

  I see that product also allow a service like saloon. Technology training also comes under service.
- `Course`

  Technology training is a Course. But it's not like typical college/university course, it's a website.
- `Event`

  Since the course keeps on happening, I am not sure if it can be an event.

Comment: Added my answer here as well. Was downvoted on SO but I can only assume it's due to it being off topic there since there was no additional feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Course

Course seems quite promising since for an online training course, it does describe your case pretty precisely.

> "A description of an educational course which may be offered as distinct instances at different times and places, or through different media or modes of study."

Unfortunately it is pending so won't be in general use yet. If you're confident in being an early adopter pick this one but you are unlikely to see benefits until search engines or other entities start processing it and it leaves pending.

## Product

For Product, you have the advantage of being the most common and generic type that is used by search engines for snippets (I note you added the SEO tag) so I would select this one to leverage the existing infrastructure, validations, and stability of this type.

## Event

For Event, it is something that happens at specific times and locations so I believe this makes it not suitable for something that is continuously available.